# How to compare words on C

Tags: c

I have no idea why this code is not working. Could someone please help me? (I want a simple version-fix if it's possible, because I've only started to study C a couple of weeks ago.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main ()
{
    char *name="alina";
    char *input;
    printf ("what's your name? \n");
    scanf ("%s",&input);
    if (input=="alina")
        printf("your name is %s good job!\n ",&name);
    if (input!="alina")
        printf("are you sure? open the program again and insert the correct name");
    while (1);
}
```

Comment: you need to allocate memory for input - have a look at malloc; to compare strings you can use somethink like strcmp

Comment: Also, get rid of `&` before `input` and `name`. They're already pointers.

Comment: could one of you give me an example of how i could write the code correctly?

Comment: Note: your last line `while (1);` is an infinite loop. What do you want to do?

Comment: i just want to keep the cmd window open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did some errors. First, if you want to insert a string, you can use the `%s`, but you have to use an array of `char` in which you can store that string. That's, you have to write something like this.

```
char input[100];
scanf("%s", input);
```

and then it'll work. This snippet of code means: I need to insert (store) a string. So first I create a place in which I can store it (pay attention that the string must be maximum of 99 characters; my array has size 100, but the last character is used to represent the end of the string), and then I use the `scanf` to write what I want.

The second error is that if you want to compare two strings, you can't simply use the `==` or `!=`, like when you do with numbers. The `string.h` library lets you use the `strcmp` function, like this:

```
if (strcmp(name, input) == 0)   // this means the strings are equal
   ...
else
   ...
```

remembering that

```
char* name = "Alina";
char input[100];
```

Eventually, here you're an inspected version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char* name = "Alina";
    char input[100];
    printf("What's your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", input);
    if (strcmp(name, input) == 0)
        printf("Your name is %s good job!\n", name);
    else
        printf("Are you sure? Open the program again and insert the correct name\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The `while(1)` at the end of your code is absolutely dangerous, because it starts an infinite loop that never ends, crashing your program. You want to definitely remove it!

Comment: thank you so much! it's finally working! about the while(1) - when i don't do it, it closes the program immediately, but when i do write it then the program remains open, so this is why i did it, but again, thank you so much!

Comment: The infinite loop doesn't crash the program; it just prevents it from terminating, and do so while keeping the CPU running flat out.  Many people programming in an IDE where the program is run in a terminal window and the window vanishes when the program exits use a variant of `getchar()` — often `getch()` on Windows — to wait for an input from the user before exiting.

Answer (score 1):

you need to apply following changes:

```
char input[256];
scanf("%s", input);
printf("your name is %s good job!\n ", name);
```

to compare strings use [`strcmp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) - have a look at documentation of this function.

be careful with `scanf` - think about how long string you can store there and what can go wrong. Have a look at `scanf_s`